# Other pronouns with "Boy, am I tired"

Tags: inversion, subject-auxiliary-inversion, exclamatives

Would this emphatic expression be used with other pronouns and other tenses?

> Boy, am I tired!

Would you give an example for each tense. An example for all cases would be best but not necessary. Seeing is believing, I mean, understanding!

These are the kinds of patterns I have in mind. You could use them as a guide but you do not have to fill in.

Set 1

- Boy, is he ...
- Boy, are you ...
- Boy, are they ...

Set 2

- Boy, was he ...
- Boy, were we ...

Set 3

- Boy, does he ...
- Boy, did they ...

---

From a link provided by Alan Carmack, definition of boy exclamation from the [Oxford Advanced American Dictionary](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/boy_2)

> - Boy, it sure is hot!
> - Oh boy! That's great!
> - Boy, it hurts!
> - Boy, am I glad to see you!
> - They eat it for breakfast and boy is it good!

Thank you, but I do not feel it fully answers my question. When it comes to languages, I cannot generalize; language is not always logical. I do not want to resort to guesses; that is not knowledge.

I hope my question conforms to the rules of the site. It is specific, and clear.

Comment: http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/boy_2

Comment: I think anything (that's grammatical as an exclamation) goes in *Boy, ...* This should work, too: *Boy, what a man!* :P -- (BTW, I think I sometimes write it like this: *Boy! What a man!* I don't know which one is more common, but I think both are fine.)

Comment: @learner - _Tense_ has no relation to **Boy**, nor to **Gee whillikers** nor to **Jumping Butterballs**, nor to any other exclamation. I could say _Jumping Butterballs, would that he were as he had been!_ and not be concerned with tense as regards the exclamation. Or do I misunderstand your question?

Answer (score 4):

In general, the expression you are asking about

> Oh boy!

is tense **independent**. You are using the short form of simply "boy!"

It is the same in meaning as

> My goodness!
>   Take note!
>   Oh my!

and is used to call attention to something.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It's just I almost always find it as in "Boy, am I ..." with few variations. It was odd I did not notice the use of man instead as in "Man, am I ...". The inversion is largely bound to boy not man. This is what I have seen. Of course, I am non-native and obviously still learning

Answer (score 2):

Both set one and two are used in English. Set 3 can also be used, though less common.

Set 1

- Boy, is he energetic today.
- Boy, are you tired this morning.
- Boy, are they loud during class time!

Set 2

- Boy, was he working hard yesterday.
- Boy, were we young back then.

Set 3

- Boy, does that fish smell bad.
- Boy, did they have fun at the concert last night.

Answer (score 0):

Boy am I.... and Man am I.... both exist, but using "boy" gives it an air of childish exuberance, whereas "man" seems more like either you're high, or complaining.